# java Math.random() from -N to N

Tags: java

I need to randomly pick a number (this is in java, using Math.random()) between -N and N. Specifically, in this current case I need to pick a random number between -1 and 1. All the results I've found has explained how to find a random number between some positive numbers.

Right now I'm using this statement, which only covers half of what I need.

```
double i = Math.random();
```

Comment: Yucky, yucky, but just for fun: `double i = Math.random() * (Math.random() > 5 ? -1 : 1);`. (although this offers 2x the amount of numbers compared to the typical solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a random number between -n and n:

```
/**
 * @return a random number, r, in the range -n <= r < n
 */
public static double getRandom(double n) {
   return Math.random()*n*2 - n;
}
```

Comment: Picking nits, but the range is actually `-n <= r < n`.

Comment: True, but equality holds with a probability of somewhere around 1 in 4 billion

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
2 * Math.random() - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for generating random numbers uniformly distributed within a range (min, max) is:

```
min + rand.nextDouble() * (max - min)
```

In your case, `max == -min == N`. Just plug in the values and simplify:

```
2 * N * rand.nextDouble() - N
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double n = 1.0;
double range = 2 * n;
double value = range * Math.random() - n;
```

You can modify the `n` value to alter the maximum/minimum value generated, for example if you need random numbers in the range `[-10, 10)` then let `n = 10.0;`

Comment: Limit is actually 2x the maximum number. Perhaps it would be apt to name it `range`?

Answer (score 0):

use random on

```
(0, 32767+32768) then subtract by 32768
```

or 
Generate numbers between `0 and 65535 then just subtract 32768`